# How can I decouple configuration in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have multiple deployments that use the same Ingress `server-snippet`, however I don't want to re-write that config in each deployment yaml. How can I organize my configs in a DRY manner?

I've looked into ConfigMaps, but I'm confused on whether or not they apply to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I general, when I'm DRYing up my manifests, in general, I reach for [`ytt`](https://get-ytt.io). It's pretty easy to pull snippets (yes, even entire resources/YAML docs) into a function and then invoke that function wherever it's needed.

Here's an example: https://get-ytt.io/#example:example-function